# Is the ethernet port connected through USB on the Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: usb, ethernet, raspberry-pi

The new Raspberry Pi 2 Model B can be ordered and it has vastly superior performance (~6x CPU and 2x RAM (B+)) compared to the first version. I always found that it is a problem that the ethernet port is connected through USB on the RPi 1. I have found it very slow to send/receive data to/from the RPi.

Is this also the case for RPi 2? The data sheet from a distributor doesn't seem to indicate either way.

Comment: The design of the circuit between the old Model B and the new Model B is the same.  This has been stated on numerous technical websites reporting the differences that do exist.

Comment: Probably better off at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Raspberry Pi questions are on topic here, so we are [hesitant to migrate them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169983/are-there-precedents-to-migrate-a-post-to-a-beta-site). Especially to Beta sites, to which we typically don't migrate. (@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, please also consider this when mentioning other sites. Always tell the OP that they should wait if their question does not receive much attention.)